# Google App Script - Remove the tab if the name of the tab does not exist in another array

Tags: google-apps-script

I`m trying to extract names of all existing tabs and compare this to another array which is kANew in this case..

Below is the code I used...

```
 function Checking() {

  var reportId = xxx
  var profileId = yyy;

  var httpOptions = {'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};       
  var additionalParameters = {'synchronous': 'true'};

  //run report and get file ID
  var ReportFile = eXelate.Reports.run(profileId, reportId, 
additionalParameters);
  var ReportFileID = (ReportFile.id);

  //
  var newReportFile = eXelate.Files.get(reportId, 
ReportFileID);
  if(newReportFile.urls) {var httpOptions = {'headers': {'Authorization': 
'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(newReportFile.urls.apiUrl, 
httpOptions).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  //past data into sheet                        
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getMaxRows(), 6000);
  sheet.deleteRows(1,6000);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, 
csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  //delete beginning and report totals
  sheet.deleteRows(1, 11);
  var sheets = new Array()
  var activess = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetss.length ; i++) sheets.push( [sheetss[i].getName() ] )
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
      sheet.deleteRows(lastrow);
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();                        
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  var rawvalues = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastrow,1).getValues();
  var rawvaluestring = rawvalues.toString();
  var sheetsforremoval = sheets.toString();
  var lR = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var kA = sheet.getRange(2,1,lR,1).getValues();
  var kANew = [].concat.apply([],kA);
   for (var i = 0; i < kANew.length; i ++){
  kANew[i] += ' Placements'
  // Make sure to push the actual raw data name and keep it in the array 
  //so that the deleteSheet doesn`t recognize raw data name as something to delete!!!!!!!!!
   }
  kANew.push('Sheet1')

      for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[2] == 0 || row[2] == '') {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++; 
    }
    }

                         }

  var obj = {};
  var ret_arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < kANew.length; i++) {
    obj[kANew[i]] = true;
  }
  for (var key in obj) {
    ret_arr.push(key);
  }
  Logger.log(ret_arr)
  for (var i = 0; i < ret_arr.length; i ++) {
    if (ret_arr.indexOf(sheetss[i]) == -1) { // what is wrong with this getName function?
    activess.deleteSheet(sheetss[i])
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code, it removes all tabs that exist in the current google sheet. It is supposed to remove the tabs if the actual name of the tab is not in this ret_arr array.

So basically, the logic behind this is, a) compare sheetss[i] against ret_arr
b) If elements in sheetss[i] isn`t found in ret_arr array, then remove that tab accordingly.

- Side note: when I try this with ".getName()" function, it returns an error saying "cannot get .getName() with undefined.

Example below...

```
  for (var i = 0; i < ret_arr.length; i ++) {
    if (ret_arr.indexOf(sheetss[i].getName()) == -1) { // what is wrong with this getName function?
    activess.deleteSheet(sheetss[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please provide me with suggestion on where I should fix so that it can only remove the relevant tabs?

Comment: `kANew` seems to be a complicated array with `length` infinitely greater than `sheetss`>`i` will be greater than `sheetss.length`> `sheetss[i]`> `undefined`

Comment: ohh maybe thats why..cuz kANew is an array filled with elements from the raw data, not unique element.

Comment: Hey @TheMaster, so I pulled only the unique elements from that kANew to reduce the # of elements. But it is now removing all tabs, not only the ones that do not exist in sheetss.

Comment: var obj = {};
  var ret_arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < kANew.length; i++) {
    obj[kANew[i]] = true;
  }
  for (var key in obj) {
    ret_arr.push(key);
  }
  Logger.log(ret_arr)
  for (var i = 0; i < ret_arr.length; i ++) {
    if (ret_arr.indexOf(sheetss[i]) == -1) { // what is wrong with this getName function?
    activess.deleteSheet(sheetss[i])
    }
  }
}

Comment: Is there something wrong with my logic??

Comment: `i<sheetss.length`

Comment: ahh shoot...... yea.. thanks for picking it up!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function deleteListedSheets() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var removeTheseSheets=['Sheet5','Sheet6','Sheet7','Sheet8'];
  var sheetsToDelete=shts.filter(function(sh){
    var name=sh.getName();
    return removeTheseSheets.indexOf(name)!=-1;
  });
  sheetsToDelete.forEach(function(sh){ss.deleteSheet(sh)});
}
```